# Another VBA Conundrum - How to save the Clipboard Contents as a PDF File

Tags: vba, pdf, printing, screen, clipboard

I've searched the web and stackoverflow for help on the task I'm facing and have found answers to some, but one is being a bit more problematic.

And before I get, "don't use VBA, use 'XYZ'", let me say that I'm not at liberty to dictate what is used. There is an existing Rockwell Software FactoryTalk View SE system in place and VBA is what I have. End of that story! :D

So what I've been asked to look into is the following. From a screen in the Factory Talk View a button would trigger a screen print and of that or a second (preferred) screen. In the event of the second screen option the button would open the second screen, take the screen print, then close the screen. In both cases the screen print would be sitting in the clipboard. This part I think I've found a solution for.

The saving the clipboard content to a PDF file is where I'm having no luck finding help or examples. How would the content of the clipboard be saved to a generic location as a PDF file?

As always, any and all relevant help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Does the code run on a machine with a MS-Office install? How about dumping clipboard contents into an Excel file, and then saving it as a PDF?

Comment: No, Office is not installed on this machine.

Comment: So what's your VBA host?

Comment: I have been able to get code to grab the screen print and using Shell with MSPaint output a jpeg file. 

I've been looking online for a way to use the TaskID of the instance of MSPaint to make Paint print the file (while it is open) to a PDF using an installed PDF printer. I have yet to find that information. Anyone privy to a way to do this?

Comment: Again, you're saying "VBA is what I have", but also "Office is not installed on this machine", so *what is your VBA host application*?

Comment: If you read my original post you will see that the host application is Rockwell Software's FactoryTalk View Site Edition. It has VBA as the scripting engine.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that. Well, good luck!

Comment: Not something I have in abundance obviously!